# JSON.stringify is distorting code adding \ inside strings?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save local storage info but what happens is I am getting \ added to all the items that are strings I mean as some answers stated it is caused by double stringfy ? issue is my blob action that saves the local storage refuse to handle the it unless is it is stringifed, long story short could this double stringfy needed for the function cause issues later, I have no problem when parsing back but the look of the saved elements looks really weird  ?

```js
//const ls = JSON.stringify(localStorage);
// "id":"\"159e17e9-19b7-453d-8e10-a411c7424586\"
// "groups":"{\"bee7bdc4-d888-46e6-93d7-ed0c\" : :[{\"id\":\"0e6e6426-4d79-4eea-9180-06111dd2a0e3\"}]
  
  
  
const config = {a: 'fdfgdg', b: 2}
console.log(JSON.stringify(config))
```

Comment: You shouldn't stringify `localStorage`. You should stringify an object or array, and store that in localStorage. Then use JSON.parse() when you retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

When **saving** to localStorage use [**JSON.stringify**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (since Storage accepts only String values):

```js
const myData = {some: "data", other: "stuff"};
localStorage.appData = JSON.stringify(myData);
```

When **reading** from localStorage, use [**JSON.parse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
const myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.appData || "{}");
console.log(myData);  // {some: "data", other: "stuff"}
```

**Don't be afraid of escaped double-quotes** with backslash! Otherwise it would end up in an invalid String format

```js
const test = "this is \"something\""; // properly escaped quotes
```

Get used to see in console (on in LocalStorage) the escaped strings used for Keys os String properties of a JSON stringified Object literal:

```js
"{\"prop\": \"some value\"}"   // Valid stringified JSON
```

perfectly fine.

Learn more about the [JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).
JSON, in order to be valid, its keys need to be enclosed in double quotes. JSON.stringify will take care of adding quotes to a JS Object Literal keys for you.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, things aren't going as planned because you are stringifying `localStorage` itself, as well as improperly stringifying and parsing your data.

It would be much easier just to save the object directly to localStorage and then retrieve it as needed, without having to fool around with stringifying and parsing. While these methods are necessary, all they accomplish is to convert your data into the format useable by localStorage anyway, but the data itself stays converted, that is, a float 122.55 is converted into a string "122.55" and it stays that way.

Wouldn't it be so much easier if you could directly store the number 122.55 and retrieve it that way also?

Have a look at [localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage), where you can transparently set/get any of the following "types": Array, Boolean, Date, Float, Integer, Null, Object or String. It seamlessly converts your data, stores it, and allows you to retrieve it just the way it went it. Store an object and get it back. Store a date and get it back. Store a number or a boolean and get those back.

Examples:

```
localDataStorage.set( 'key1', false );
localDataStorage.get( 'key1' );   -->   false (boolean)

localDataStorage.set( 'key2', 122.55 );
localDataStorage.get( 'key2' );   -->   122.55 (float)

var obj = {
    id: '159e17e9-19b7-453d-8e10-a411c7424586',
    groups: '000e17e9-19b7-453d-8e10-a411c7424500'
}
localDataStorage.set( 'key3', obj );
localDataStorage.get( 'key3' );   -->   {id: '159e17e9-19b7-453d-8e10-a411c7424586', groups: '000e17e9-19b7-453d-8e10-a411c7424500'} (object)

localDataStorage.set( 'key4', "this is \"something\"" );
localDataStorage.get( 'key4' );   -->   'this is "something"' (string)
```

All of the conversion work is done in the background for you: just set/get and go.

[DISCLAIMER] I am the author of the utility [/DISCLAIMER]

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting a stringfied object and you want him to become an object again, there is another command to do so

```
JSON.parse(obj)
```

```js
var obj = {
    id: '159e17e9-19b7-453d-8e10-a411c7424586',
    groups: '000e17e9-19b7-453d-8e10-a411c7424500'
}

var stringfiedObject = JSON.stringify(obj)
console.log(stringfiedObject)

var objectFromStringfiedObject = JSON.parse(stringfiedObject)
console.log(objectFromStringfiedObject)
```

Comment: in my code it adds / for some reason, and I don't know why.

Comment: @Richardson there's an answer here that explains why.

Comment: You need to use JSON.parse command as I mentioned above. You’re trying to deserialize using a command to serialize, it’s quite the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "extra backslash", it's just your means of output show that extra backslash, because it is the way it renders string values (you probably use browser console for that, didn't you?).

Be sure, the actual stringified value does not contain any characters that are not supposed to be there.

Comment: const config = {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(config))) "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}"

Comment: this is what happens when I stringfy object !! is it clean ????

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I've said :-)

Comment: the point is i am saving the local storage value to text file and i can see those \ in there

Comment: do you have the code demoing the way you save it to the text file?